# Formation: So much heat, where does it all go?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

I was comparing heat of formation numbers with specific heat values, and the numbers look really weird.

Take a typical example like magnesium fluoride. Its $\Delta H$ is -1124 kJ/mol and its heat capacity is almost certainly less than 0.1 kJ/mol K. Divide and you get at least 11000 Kelvins!

So the heat of formation doesn't seem to go into raising the temperature of the product. It can't be going into the surroundings either; otherwise the reaction would vaporize anything nearby. Where *does* it go, or what's wrong with my reasoning?

**Edit**: OK so let's not use a fluorine compound. Take aluminum nitride. -318 kJ/mol. Are we really going to suggest aluminum burns in nitrogen at over 3000 K?

**Edit**: Si<sub>3</sub>N<sub>4</sub>: -745 kJ/mol.

**Edit**: Regarding the article on adiabatic flame temperature: aluminum burns in oxygen at 4000 K. The $\Delta H$ of Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> is -1680 kJ/mol. 1680/(4000-298) = 0.45 kJ/mol K. This would be a fantastic heat capacity whether we're talking constant pressure or constant volume.

Comment: Well, I can certainly imagine that magnesium "burns" pretty extremly in a fluorine atmosphere. And magnesium burns with >3000°C in air.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_flame_temperature

Comment: Magnesium burns vigorously in carbon dioxide with a very hot flame. I hesitate to think just how well it burns in fluorine. But I guess it might produce a lot of heat.

Comment: For these extremely exothermic reactions, a lot of energy is carried away in the form of photons, limiting how hot it can get. Recall that the power dissipated by a black body radiator is proportional to $T^4$, so it rises very quickly as the reaction becomes hotter.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto - I wish I could accept comments as answers.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't seem to understand the precise definition of heat of formation.   You are aware that it is related to the heat released or absorbed in the formation of chemical bonds, correct?

Comment: @ChesterMiller - Yes. I really don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is some more to the question than what I wrote. From what I understand, these adiabatic flame temperatures should in principle not be affected by emission of thermal radiation, but they are all significantly smaller than what your back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests

Comment: What is your precise definition of the heat of formation?  (I know the definition, but I want to know your understanding of what it is)

Comment: My understanding is that the heat of formation is disordered energy liberated when atoms bind to each other. I think binding involves changes to electronic energy modes (molecular orbitals) so the electrons experience an average reduction in their potential energy.

Comment: Yikes.  That's getting into a level of detail that I was hoping to avoid.  Here's my understanding:  You start off with elements that will react to form into a chemical compound, so the initial state is the elements in their natural states at a specified temperature and 1 bar pressure.  The final state is the compound at the same temperature and pressure.  The heat of formation is the amount of heat you need to add to the reaction mixture during this process, such that the final temperature of the compound is the same as the initial temperature of the elements.

Comment: So when the $\Delta H$ is negative, the reaction is exothermic, meaning heat comes from the reaction. Where does it go if not into degrees of freedom of the products (three of which define the temperature) and maybe some EM radiation?

Comment: It doesn't.  The heat is generated by forming chemical bonds.  In the definition of $\Delta H$, when it is negative, this amount of heat must be removed from the reaction mixture (i.e., transferred to the surroundings) in order to maintain the temperature of the mixture  constant at its pre-reaction value.

Comment: It's typically not EM radiation.  The heat is typically transferred to the surroundings by conduction/convection to a constant temperature reservoir (such as a liquid/solid mixture at its melting point).

Comment: I'm imagining the energy from a mole of product going into a few kilograms of ice and being just enough to melt it. Maybe that does make sense. I'm satisfied for now. If you write up an answer I'll accept it.